# IFTTT: How to email me my Feedly feeds once a day?

Tags: if-this-then-that

Is there a way for IFTTT to send me an email that contains all my Feedly feeds (or a specific source) within a 24 hour period, instead of sending me an email on every article?

Comment: I'm not sure that ifttt has a native way to daily digest-ify feeds, but [this recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/67053) seems to be solving this problem using a combination of yahoo pipes and ifttt.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [this](https://ifttt.com/recipes/175410-email-new-articles-from-feedly-as-daily-digest) recipe will do what you are after:

[image]